# Is $\nabla_w w^th= \nabla_w h^tw =h$ True? (While studying Hessian of least squares)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, vector-analysis

I heard that:

$\nabla_w w^th= \nabla_w h^tw =h$ ($w$ and $h$ are vectors)

While I calculate Hessian of $f(w) =$$\frac{1}{2} ||Xw-y||^2 $= $\frac12(Xw-y)^T(Xw-y)$

$\nabla_w f(w)$ = $\nabla_w w^tX^tXw$ +.....

Then $\nabla_w w^tX^tXw = \nabla_ww^t(X^tXw) = X^tXw$

What did I wrong? Actually I know the answer is wrong, but I don't find any wrong on it...

Comment: First of all, since both $w$ and $h$ are vectors, then $w^th=h^tw$. This gives an answer to your first point.

For the second point, now you have a quadratic form in $w$. So, there is a factor 2 missing there.

Comment: @KBS But (X^tXw) is a vector.... so I am still curious

Comment: Yes, but it depends on $w$. Check the difference between computing the derivative of $\alpha w$ and $\alpha w^2$ with respect to $w$ for some scalars $\alpha,w$.